# Craps game and function

Tags: c

I'm creating a sort of craps game using C.

if sum=7,11 win;
if sum=2,3,12 lose;
else continue.

I have some problems with the function play_game() because the return of the function isn't correct. For example, if the sum is 3 sometimes doesn't return 1 but 2.

```
int roll_dice(void);
int play_game(void);
int main(){
    int sum;
    char play;

    do{
        roll_dice();
        play_game();

        if (play_game()==0){
            printf ("\nYou win!");  
            printf ("\nPlay again? ");
            play=getchar(); 
        }
        else {
            if (play_game()==1) {
                printf ("\nYou lose!"); 
                printf ("\nPlay again? ");
                play=getchar(); 
            }   
            else {
                if (play_game()==2) play='y';
                else system ("pause");
            }   
        }                   
    }
    while (play=='y');
    return 0;       
}

int roll_dice(void){
    int sum = rand()%6 + rand()%6;
    return sum;
}


int play_game(void){
    int sum = roll_dice();
    printf ("\nYou rolled: %d", sum);
    if ((sum==7)||(sum==11)) return 0;
    else {
        if ((sum==2)||(sum==3)||(sum==12)) return 1;    
        else {
            printf ("\nYour point is %d", sum);
            return 2;   
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: It is impossible for `play_game()` to return 2 if sum is 3.

Comment: The dice seem to be 0-5 in your code instead of 1-6.

Answer (score 5):

You're calling `play_game` too often.

You call it once at the start of the loop but discard the result.  You call it again and check if the result is 0.  If it is not, you call it *again* and check if the result is 1, if not you call it *again* and check if the result is 2.

You need to call `play_game` only once in each loop and store the return value so you can check it later without calling the function again.

```
do{
    const int result = play_game();   // save result

    if (result ==0){      // use saved result
        printf ("\nYou win!");  
        printf ("\nPlay again? ");
        play=getchar(); 
    }
    else {
        if (result ==1) {     // use saved result
            printf ("\nYou lose!"); 
            printf ("\nPlay again? ");
            play=getchar(); 
        }   
        else {
            if (result ==2) play='y';    // use saved result
            else system ("pause");
        }   
    }                   
}
while (play=='y');
```

Comment: Better make that `const int result = play_game();` for clarity's sake.

Comment: After two loops the program ends and I don't understand why.

Comment: @Walter The `getchar` function reads all characters, including newlines.  If you read a newline, you need to keep calling `getchar` until you get something else.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the algorithm problems pointed out in [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47393304/2410359) fine answer, the dice rolls are not simulated correctly. [@Klas Lindbäck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393145/craps-game-and-function#comment81739461_47393145)

```
// better name: roll_2dice()
int roll_dice(void){
    // int sum = rand()%6 + rand()%6;  // wrong simulation
    int sum = (rand()%6 + 1) + (rand()%6 + 1); // corrected.
    return sum;
}
```

Further, a good `rand()` tends to be expensive in computational time.  Alternative that only uses 1 `rand()` call

```
int roll_2dice(void){
    int r = rand()%36;  // 36 combinations
    int die1 = r/6 + 1;
    int die2 = r%6 + 1;
    return die1 + die2;
}
```